# Dojo: Is there an event after drag & drop finished

Tags: dojo, events, drag-and-drop

I've got two dojo.dnd.Sources with items. Whenever an item is dropped I need to persist the new order of the items in the Sources using an xhr.

Is there an dojo event or topic that is fired after an dnd operation has (successfully) finished? What would be the best way to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably I don't understand the problem in all details but I don't see why you need to process events or topics. The best way to record changes is to intercept updating methods on relevant sources. Specifically you need to intercept `insertNodes()` for drops or any other additions.

Simple example (pseudo-code):

```
var source1, source2;
// ...
// initialize sources
// populate sources
// ...

function getAllItems(source){
  var items = source.getAllNodes().map(function(node){
    return source.getItem(node.id);
  });
  return items;
}

function dumpSource(source){
  var items = getAllItems(source);
  // XHR items here to your server
}

function recordChange(){
  // now we know that some change has occured
  // it could be a drop or some programmatic updates
  // we don't really care
  dumpSource(source1);
  dumpSource(source2);
}

dojo.connect(source1, "insertNodes", recordChanges);
dojo.connect(source2, "insertNodes", recordChanges);
// now any drop or other change will trigger recordChanges()
// after the change has occurred.
```

You can try to be smart about that and send some diff information instead of a whole list, but it is up to you to generate it — you have everything you need for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dojo.subscribe` to do something when a drop is finished like so:

```
dojo.subscribe("/dnd/drop", function(source, nodes, copy, target) {
  // do your magic here
});
```

There's examples of using subscribe on the [dojotoolkit tests site](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojo/tests/dnd/test_dnd.html).  More info about dojo [publish](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/publish) and [subscribe](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/subscribe) too.

Alternately, you could connect to the `onDndDrop` method.

```
var source = new dojo.dnd.Source( ... );
dojo.connect( source, "onDndDrop", function( source, nodes, copy, target ) {
  // make magic happen here
});
```

connect methods are called at the end so the items will be there at that point.

Comment: The dropped element does has not yet arrived if I use "/dnd/drop". Its still at the source. I found some magic to do what I want using setTimeout.

Comment: Exactly what I was gonna add. Aren't there any better ways of doing this though? I want to update my sub panel as per the tree updates on dnd. Surely it should be faster and I can not predetermine how many tree elements out there.. its all dynamic so update timing could be vary. I tried to use deferred without much success. any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm keeping this note for dojo Tree folks just like me who would run in to this problem. Solutions given here was not quite worked well in my situation. I was using a dijit.tree.dndSource with Dojo tree and subscribing to "/dnd/drop" allows me to capture the event even though at that point my underlying data store hadn't been updated with latest changes. So I tried waiting as Wienczny explains, that doesn't solve the problem completely as I can't rely on a timeout to do the waiting job. Time taken for store update could be vary, i.e. shorter or very long depends on how complex your data structure is. I found the solution with overriding the onDndDrop method of the dndController. Simply you can specify the onDndDrop :   on your tree initialization. One thing I found odd though you can not hitch this method, you will get weird behavior during dnd.

Tree

```
                this._tree = new MapConfigTree({
                checkAcceptance: this.dndAccept,
                onDndDrop: this.onDndDrop,
                betweenThreshold:5,
```

method

```
            onDndDrop : function(source, nodes, copy, target){
            if(source.dropPosition === 'Over' && (target.targetAnchor.item.type[0] == 'Test layer')) {
                this.inherited(arguments);
                // do your bit here 
            } else {
                this.onDndCancel();
            }   
        }
```